# Prove that $-\psi(y) \leq c(x,y) + c(x,\bar y) - \psi(\bar y)$

Tags: inequality, supremum-and-infimum, monotone-functions, optimal-transport

In the book Optimal Transport for Applied Mathematicians, Theorem 1.37, the authors states an inequality, but I'm having trouble seeing how one shows that the inequality is indeed true.

**Definition**: Given a function $c:X\times Y \to \mathbb R$, we say that $\Gamma \subset X \times Y$ is $c$-cyclically monotone ($c$-CM) if for every $k \in \mathbb N$, every permutation $\sigma$ and every finite family of points $(x_1,y_1),...,(x_k,y_k) \in \Gamma$ we have
$$
\sum^k_{i=1} c(x_i,y_i) \leq
\sum^k_{i=1} c(x_i,y_{\sigma(i)})
$$

Now, assume that $\Gamma$ is $c$-CM. Then, fix $(x_0, y_0) \in \Gamma$, and define:
$$
-\psi(y) = \inf\{
-c(x_n,y) +c(x_n,y_{n-1})-c(x_{n-1},y_{n-1})+...+ c(x_1,y_0) - c(x_0,y_0) : n \in \mathbb N,
(x_i,y_i) \in \Gamma \quad  \forall i=1,...,n
\}
$$

How does one then shows that fo $(x,y) \in \Gamma$ and $\bar y \in \text{Proj}_y \circ\Gamma$, we can then write:
$$
-\psi(y) \leq - c(x,y) + c(x,\bar y) - \psi(\bar y)
$$

In the proof, the author claims that this inequality follows from the very definition of the function $\psi$. What I found odd was that since $y$ and $\bar y$ are arbitrary, then I could just swap them, obtaining the opposite inequality, and hence, I actually have an equality. Which would be kind of odd. Anyways, how can you prove this inequality? And is it actually an equality?

Comment: I guess that $\mathbb R+\{+\infty\}$ means $\mathbb R\cup\{+\infty\}$, $\sigma$  is a permutation of $\{1,\dots,n\}$, and $\text{Proj}_y \circ\Gamma$ is the projection of the set $\Gamma$ on the second coordinate. We have $(x,y)\in\Gamma$ and I don’t know whether $(x,\bar y)\in\Gamma$, so maybe because of that we cannot swap $y$ and $\bar y$.
Also I guess that the considered inequality should be $-\psi(y) \leq {\color{red} -}c(x,y) + c(x,\bar y) - \psi(\bar y).$

Comment: Thanks for finding the typos. Actually $c:X\times Y \to \mathbb R$. And yes, I wrote the wrong inequality. Just fixed it.

Comment: Now the required claim looks more plausible, but I still have problems showing it. Is the right-hand side of the definition of $-\psi(y)$ correct? (It looks suspiciously that it is does not contain $y_n$).

Comment: Yep, now I guess it's all good. Now that you pointed out that $(x,\bar y)$ might not be in $\Gamma$, I think you just made me understand what I was confused about. Because, the $y$ seemed arbitrary, so you could swipe the inequality, hence get equality. Which would be kind of bonkers considering the context of the theorem.

Comment: You can just consider that your $y$ is the $y_n$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, so after some struggle and the help of a friend I figured what I was misunderstanding. Here is the proof:

First, note that since $\bar y \in \pi_y\circ\Gamma$, this means that $\exists \quad  \bar x : (\bar x,\bar y) \in \Gamma$. Also, note that
$\{(x,y),(\bar x, \bar y)\} \subset \Gamma$, henece
$$
-\psi(y) \leq -c(x,y) + c(x,\bar y) - c(\bar x, \bar y)
$$

Now, fix the first two terms in the inequality. Note that for any $n \in \mathbb N$ and $(x_i,y_i) \in \Gamma$ for $i \in \{0,...,n\}$, we have:
$$
-\psi(y) \leq -c(x,y) + c(x,\bar y) - c(\bar x_n, \bar y) + c(\bar x_n,\bar y)-...-c(\bar x_0,\bar y_0)
$$

We can then conclude that
$$
-\psi(y) \leq -c(x,y) + c(x,\bar y) +
\inf \{-c(\bar x_n, \bar y) +...-c(\bar x_0,\bar y_0): n\in \mathbb N
, (\bar x_i,\bar y_i) \in \Gamma \quad \forall i \in \{0,...,n\} \} \\
-\psi(y) \leq -c(x,y) + c(x,\bar y) -\psi(\bar y)
$$

Answer (score 1):

By assumption $-\psi(\bar{y})>-\infty$. Thus, there is a cycle $\Gamma':=\lbrace (x_{1},y_{1}),\dots,(x_{r},y_{r})\rbrace$ such that $-\psi(\bar{y})=-c(x_{r},\bar{y})+c(x_{r},y_{r-1})+\dots+c(x_{1},y_{0})-c(x_{0},y_{0})$. Then, considering the cylce $\Gamma'':=\Gamma'\cup\lbrace{(x,\bar{y})\rbrace}$ it follows
\begin{equation}
-\psi(y)\le -c(x,y)+\sum_{k=1}^{r+1} c(x_{k},y_{k-1})-c(x_{k-1},y_{k-1})-c(x_{0},y_{0})=-c(x,y)+c(x,\bar{y})-\psi(\bar{y}).
\end{equation}

Comment: Why does $(x,\bar y) \in Gamma$? Or are you not claiming that?

Comment: Does this inequality actually imply an equality? Also, how do you know that the infimum is ever reached?

Comment: No, it should not. Admittedly, my answer needs some revision but I'm pretty busy at the moment. Eventually, I wanted to adopt the argument from https://www.him.uni-bonn.de/uploads/media/TransportProblem-Bonn.1.pdf   Maybe you or someone else is faster.